# /etc/shadow file access without sudo?

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu, shadow

I've recently been learning a little bit about Linux security and I want to model some stuff on my own computer (ubuntu) and I've been wondering...does anyone know if or how you can read the /etc/shadow file without needing admin privileges

(perhaps a boot disk or something?) Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be looking for `/etc/passwd` instead

Comment: Yes, as you suggested, you could read it using a boot disk, unless the partition /etc/shadow is on is encrypted.

Comment: @imm: if the boot up process is completely automated, then any hypothetical key for the filesystem is probably available on the machine in plaintext (or something near enough to plain text).

Comment: @sarnold: The encryption is repeatable, not reproducible.  The OS doesn't decrypt the password to compare to what the user types in, it encrypts what the user types in and compares the result to the encrypted password.  This one-way encryption scheme is called a cryptographic hash.  Oh wait, you meant encryption of the filesystem... decrypting the filesystem isn't enough, since the /etc/shadow file itself uses crypto.

Comment: @Ben: Hey, JacKeown just asked about reading the file, he never said anything about the passphrases hashed inside. I presume [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) is good enough for that. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sitting at the machine the easiest mechanism is to modify the kernel command line at bootup to include `init=/bin/sh`. This will run the shell instead of the usual [SysV `init`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style) or [`upstart`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) or [`systemd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) system boot up procedure, and the shell will give you access to anything you like, no questions asked.

This is why it is important to set a password on your grub configuration (`info grub -s security`). The bootdisk option you suggest is a reason why it is important to set a BIOS password on your machine. And removing the hard drive is a reason why it is best to put your machine in a heavy, locked, cabinet that can provide you with the level of security you wish.